# How to convert Photoshop drop shadow parameters to Illustrator drop shadow parameters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, drop-shadow

The parameters of the Drop Shadow effect in *Photoshop* are blend mode, colour, opacity, distance, **spread, and size**.

In *Illustrator*, they are colour, opacity, x-offset, y-offset, and **blur**.

I am struggling to recreate my Photoshop shadow effect in Illustrator. I understand the relationship between distance in Photoshop and x,y-offsets in Illustrator. Blur is what I am stuck at. Is there a metric/formula I can use to copy the shadow attributes from Photoshop to Illustrator?

Comment: IT depends on the document raster settings and the resolution of your Photoshop document. A..aand, whether or not you use pixels as units in illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting a nice question.
After repetetive attempts i obsorved that "Illustrator drop shadow blur" is 3 times of "drop shadow size in Photoshop". seems some fun observation.

photoshop dropdow shadow size = 10
Illustrator dropdoshadow Blur = (10/3)3.3
only the slight difference is Illustraor shadow smoothness (vector lines), photoshop shadow(raster).

[image][image]

Comment: Is this independent of selected document resolution in either application?

Comment: @Vincent YES it is

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to bring **spread** in the equation? That would be very helpful.